# How to add a custom page with cross-sell products

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1, cross-sells

You wouldn't believe how much time I've spent researching/trying to make this happen. All I want is to have an extra page come up in the order process after the product page asking the customer which cross-sell product(s) they want to add to their order (I would call them up-sell but I guess the Magento lingo is "cross-sell"). I really find it unbelievable that more businesses don't want this (I think "up-selling" can greatly increase profits and what's built into Magento does not really work so well (I have more than **20** "Cross-sell" products and they don't even fit/show on there).

I'm using Magento ver. 1.9.1.0.

I just installed the Porto Theme #11 if that makes a difference

**NEW INFO: I've been trying to implement this but no luck so far. I even have someone helping me now but we can't figure it out. Can someone please give step-by-step instructions on how to do this? (ANY solution would be much appreciated)**.

I would like it to work similar to what proflowers.com has (see the enclosed screenshot): [image]

**They have this page come up as the next step AFTER customer adds a product to the cart (clicks on PROCEED TO CHECKOUT)**

*All the cross-sell products are **ALWAYS** **the SAME** for everyone (every product ordered)*

---

Edited on November 15th, 2016:

The solution that got awarded the 100 reputation actually works. Anyone trying to do what I am trying to do should download the files and upload them into your root directory and then add the following code in your **`app/code/community/TM/SuggestPage/controllers/IndexControlle‌​‌​r.php`** file:

```
$block2 =  $this->getLayout()->createBlock('checkout/cart_coupon')->setTemplate('checkout/cart/coupon.phtml');
$this->getLayout()->getBlock('content')->append($block2);
```

---

I am still trying to figure out how to display 12 products on the special Cross-sell page instead of just 4. Accoring to @MurtuzaZabuawala - this should be done by modifying the  **crosssell.phtml** file in:

`app/design/frontend/YourPackge/YourTheme/checkout/cart/`

I found  **my crossell.phtml here**:

`/public_html/app/design/frontend/smartwave/porto/template/checkout/cart`

(I hope it's the right one - I have the Porto Theme installed)

**Here is what it looks like:**

```
<?php
/**
 * Cart cross sell items template
 *
 * @see Mage_Checkout_Block_Cart_Crosssell
 */
$store = Mage::app()->getStore();
$code  = $store->getCode();
$aspect_ratio = Mage::getStoreConfig("porto_settings/category/aspect_ratio",$code);
$ratio = ($aspect_ratio || (!$aspect_ratio && Mage::getStoreConfig("porto_settings/category/ratio_width",$code) == 0))?1:(Mage::getStoreConfig("porto_settings/category/ratio_height",$code)/Mage::getStoreConfig("porto_settings/category/ratio_width",$code));
?>
<?php if($this->getItemCount()): ?>
<div class="crosssell">
    <h2><?php echo $this->__('Based on your selection, you may be interested in the following items:') ?></h2>
    <ul id="crosssell-products-list" class="row">
    <?php foreach ($this->getItems() as $_item): ?>
        <li class="item col-sm-6 col-md-3">
            <a class="product-image" href="<?php echo $_item->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_item->getName()) ?>"><img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_item, 'thumbnail')->resize(84,84*$ratio); ?>" width="84" height="<?php echo 84*$ratio ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_item->getName()) ?>" /></a>
            <div class="product-details">
                <h3 class="product-name"><a href="<?php echo $_item->getProductUrl() ?>"><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_item->getName()) ?></a></h3>
                <?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_item, true) ?>
                <button type="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?>" class="button btn-cart" onclick="setLocation('<?php echo $this->getAddToCartUrl($_item) ?>')"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?></span></span></button>
                <ul class="add-to-links">
                    <?php if ($this->helper('wishlist')->isAllow()) : ?>
                        <li><a href="<?php echo $this->getAddToWishlistUrl($_item) ?>" class="link-wishlist"><?php echo $this->__('Add to Wishlist') ?></a></li>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                    <?php if($_compareUrl=$this->getAddToCompareUrl($_item)): ?>
                        <li><span class="separator">|</span> <a href="<?php echo $_compareUrl ?>" class="link-compare"><?php echo $this->__('Add to Compare') ?></a></li>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul>
    <script type="text/javascript">decorateList('crosssell-products-list', 'none-recursive')</script>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

---

EDITED December 2nd, 2016:

This is a great solution which works perfect especially if you want to assign different cross-sell products to each product individually. In my case - I want all of my products to have the EXACT SAME cross-sell products and I want to be able to change that depending on the season so I decided to have the extra step in the check-out (solution provided by Murtuza Zabuawala below) display products from a special category I created just for this reason. Murtuza Zabuawala did a great job with. I'm just missing the final step here:

When I put in the code which should display the products from a specific category:

```
$block = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('catalog/product_list')->set‌​CategoryId(157)->set‌​Template('catalog/pr‌​oduct/list.phtml'); $this->getLayout()->getBlock('content')->append($block);
```

I get the following Error message:

```
> There has been an error processing your request
> 
> 
> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an
> error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
> MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')' at line 1,
> query was: SELECT `mg_catalog_category_entity`.* FROM
> `mg_catalog_category_entity` WHERE (entity_id =)
> 
> Trace:
> #0 /home/mystore/public_html/lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(110):
> Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
> #1 /home/mystore/public_html/app/code/core/Zend/Db/Statement.php(291): Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_execute(Array)
> #2 /home/mystore/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(480): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
> #3 /home/mystore/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238):
> Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('SELECT `mg_cata...', Array)
> #4 /home/mystore/public_html/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(428): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('SELECT `mg_cata...', Array)
> #5 /home/mystore/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(756): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query(Object(Varien_Db_Select), Array)
> #6 /home/mystore/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Abstract.php(943):
> Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->fetchRow(Object(Varien_Db_Select))
> #7 /home/mystore/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Abstract.php(698):
> Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Abstract->load(Object(Mage_Catalog_Model_Category),
> Object(Mage_Catalog_Model_Category), NULL)
> #8 /home/mystore/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Abstract.php(225):
> Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Abstract->load(Object(Mage_Catalog_Model_Category),
> Object(Mage_Catalog_Model_Category), NULL)
> #9 /home/mystore/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/List.php(80):
> Mage_Core_Model_Abstract->load(Object(Mage_Catalog_Model_Category))
> #10 /home/mystore/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/List.php(142):
> Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List->_getProductCollection()
> #11 /home/mystore/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(918):
> Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List->_beforeToHtml()
> #12 /home/mystore/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Text/List.php(43):
> Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
> #13 /home/mystore/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919):
> Mage_Core_Block_Text_List->_toHtml()
> #14 /home/mystore/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(637):
> Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
> #15 /home/mystore/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(581):
> Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml('content', true)
> #16 /home/mystore/public_html/app/design/frontend/smartwave/porto/template/page/1column.phtml(49):
> Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildHtml('content')
> #17 /home/mystore/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241):
> include('/home/mystore/pu...')
> #18 /home/mystore/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272):
> Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('frontend/smartw...')
> #19 /home/mystore/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286):
> Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
> #20 /home/mystore/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919):
> Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
> #21 /home/mystore/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(555):
> Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
> #22 /home/mystore/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(390):
> Mage_Core_Model_Layout->getOutput()
> #23 /home/mystore/public_html/app/code/community/TM/SuggestPage/controllers/IndexController.php(32):
> Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->renderLayout()
> #24 /home/mystore/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418):
> TM_SuggestPage_IndexController->indexAction()
> #25 /home/mystore/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250):
> Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('index')
> #26 /home/mystore/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172):
> Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
> #27 /home/mystore/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354):
> Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
> #28 /home/mystore/public_html/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
> #29 /home/mystore/public_html/index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
> #30 {main}
```

---

my

> app/code/community/TM/SuggestPage/controllers/IndexControlle‌​‌​r.php

looks like this:

> ```
> <?php
>
> class TM_SuggestPage_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action
> {
>     public function indexAction()
>
>
> {
>
>     $this->loadLayout()
>         ->_initLayoutMessages('checkout/session')
>         ->_initLayoutMessages('catalog/session');
>
>
>
> $block2 =  $this->getLayout()->createBlock('checkout/cart_coupon')->setTemplate('checkout/cart/coupon.phtml');
> $this->getLayout()->getBlock('content')->append($block2);
>
>
>     $_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load(1); //here 1 is product Id
>     $block = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('catalog/product_list')->set‌​CategoryId(157)->set‌​Template('catalog/pr‌​oduct/list.phtml'); $this->getLayout()->getBlock('content')->append($block);
>
>
>
>     $this->renderLayout();
>     }
> }
> ```

---

When **I tried the following code instead** (in: `app/code/community/TM/SuggestPage/controllers/IndexControlle‌​‌​r.php` ):

**

```
$category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load(190);  
   $block = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('catalog/product_list')->set‌​Category($category)->set‌​Template('catalog/pr‌​oduct/list.phtml'); $this->getLayout()->getBlock('content')->append($block);
```

**

- it gave me this **Error**:

> ```
> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
> ```
>
> MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')' at line 1,
>   query was: SELECT `mg_catalog_category_entity`.* FROM
>   `mg_catalog_category_entity` WHERE (entity_id =)
>
> ```
> Trace:
> #0 /home/mystore/public_html/lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(110):
> ```
>
> Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
>       #1 /home/mystore/public_html/app/code/core/Zend/Db/Statement.php(291):
>   Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_execute(Array)
>       #2 /home/mystore/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(480):
>   Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
>       #3 /home/mystore/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238):
>   Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('SELECT `mg_cata...', Array)
>       #4 /home/mystore/public_html/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(428):
>   Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('SELECT`mg_cata...', Array)
>       #5 /home/mystore/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(756):
>   Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query(Object(Varien_Db_Select), Array)
>       #6 /home/mystore/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Abstract.php(943):
>   Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->fetchRow(Object(Varien_Db_Select))
>       #7 /home/mystore/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Abstract.php(698):
>   Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Abstract->load(Object(Mage_Catalog_Model_Category),
>   Object(Mage_Catalog_Model_Category), NULL)
>       #8 /home/mystore/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Abstract.php(225):
>   Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Abstract->load(Object(Mage_Catalog_Model_Category),
>   Object(Mage_Catalog_Model_Category), NULL)
>       #9 /home/mystore/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/List.php(80):
>   Mage_Core_Model_Abstract->load(Object(Mage_Catalog_Model_Category))
>       #10 /home/mystore/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/List.php(142):
>   Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List->_getProductCollection()
>       #11 /home/mystore/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(918):
>   Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List->_beforeToHtml()
>       #12 /home/mystore/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Text/List.php(43):
>   Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
>       #13 /home/mystore/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919):
>   Mage_Core_Block_Text_List->_toHtml()
>       #14 /home/mystore/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(637):
>   Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
>       #15 /home/mystore/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(581):
>   Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml('content', true)
>       #16 /home/mystore/public_html/app/design/frontend/smartwave/porto/template/page/1column.phtml(49):
>   Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildHtml('content')
>       #17 /home/mystore/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241):
>   include('/home/mystore/pu...')
>       #18 /home/mystore/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272):
>   Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('frontend/smartw...')
>       #19 /home/mystore/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286):
>   Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
>       #20 /home/mystore/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919):
>   Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
>       #21 /home/mystore/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(555):
>   Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
>       #22 /home/mystore/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(390):
>   Mage_Core_Model_Layout->getOutput()
>       #23 /home/mystore/public_html/app/code/community/TM/SuggestPage/controllers/IndexController.php(33):
>   Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->renderLayout()
>       #24 /home/mystore/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418):
>   TM_SuggestPage_IndexController->indexAction()
>       #25 /home/mystore/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250):
>   Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('index')
>       #26 /home/mystore/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172):
>   Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
>       #27 /home/mystore/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354):
>   Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
>       #28 /home/mystore/public_html/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
>       #29 /home/mystore/public_html/index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
>       #30 {main}
>
> ```
> Error log record number: 573016373867
> ```

---

**Does my Controller.php suppose to look like this?**

> ```
> <?php
>
>
> class TM_SuggestPage_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action
> {
>     public function indexAction()
>
>
> {
>
>     $this->loadLayout()
>         ->_initLayoutMessages('checkout/session')
>         ->_initLayoutMessages('catalog/session');
>
>
> $block2 =  $this->getLayout()->createBlock('checkout/cart_coupon')->setTemplate('checkout/cart/coupon.phtml');
> $this->getLayout()->getBlock('content')->append($block2);
>
>
>     $_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load(1); //here 1 is product Id
>     $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load(190);  
>    $block = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('catalog/product_list')->set‌​Category($category)->set‌​Template('catalog/pr‌​oduct/list.phtml');
> ```
>
> $this->getLayout()->getBlock('content')->append($block);
>
> ```
>     $this->renderLayout();
>     }
> }
> ```

---

**EDITED December 29th, 2016:**

*The solution posted by Murtuza Zabuawala is great! The only thing I still need to do is put some code in to call up (display) products from a specific category instead of the actual cross-sell items. Any idea how to do that?*

Comment: I think this could work for you http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/95972/cross-sell-product-is-not-showing-in-the-product-detail-page?rq=1

Comment: you want the page to be displayed after a product is added to cart or when the customer proceeds to checkout?

Comment: Your question is confusing,  Please clarify your question. Do you need your customer to redirect to upselling products(upselling product page) of the product that's been added to cart?

Comment: [(http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/95972/cross-sell-product-is-not-showing-in-the-product-detail-page?rq=1](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/95972/cross-sell-product-is-not-showing-in-the-product-detail-page?rq=1) this link will helpful for you.

Comment: Raul Sanchez - Thank you but this is NOT my problem (my Cross-sell product is showing in the product detail page) but what I'm after is creating an extra page in the Check-out process with just cross-sell products because I have more than 20 cross-sell products and they will never fit on the product page and the customer will not see them there...

Comment: Marius - any way would be fine but I think when they click to proceed to the checkout may be easier...just like proflowers.com has it working

Comment: ForgeOnline - thank you for trying to help. What I'm after is increase sales by displaying a special page (a new step in the checkout?) with cross-sell products (I have more than 20 so they do not fit on the product page and also most customers wouldn't even see them on the product page). This way - they will have it as a checkout step and they can't miss it. Let's say you have a flower shop - you could be offering chocolates, balloons, teddy bears etc. this way...

Comment: jigs parmar - Thank you for trying to help. The link you included does not help because that is not my problem. I need a special page (a new step in the checkout) where I will place all of my cross-sell products (I have more than 20 and want to make sure customers really see them and consider them). I want something similar to what proflowers.com have in their checkout process (please see the screenshot above)

Comment: Murtuza Zabuawala: Thank you. I will try to upload those files now. One question - on the GitHub page - it keeps mentioning up to 1.4.1. I have 1.9.1 - is that OK?

Comment: @Allysin enable template path hint and check from which phtml this block is coming

Comment: @Murtuza Zabuawala Thank you but I'm afraid this will be above of what I'm able to do...I think the limit is the same one as appears in the cross-sell section on the product details page...Maybe there is a way to increase that somewhere in the Admin panel?

Comment: @Murtuza Zabuawala  I found this but seems really complicated: [http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/17594/how-to-increase-the-number-of-crosssell-items-in-cart]

Comment: @Allysin I have updated my answer

Comment: @Allysin check my new answer

Comment: @Murtuza Zabuawala I did and it gave me a different Error. I posted that one on top also (in my original post)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Install below extension that will help you to create extra page after cart

https://github.com/tmhub/suggestpage

above extension add extra page after cart and that page you will add these code and you will get cross-sell product data

change your indexController indexAction as below

```
public function indexAction()
{
    $this->loadLayout()
        ->_initLayoutMessages('checkout/session')
        ->_initLayoutMessages('catalog/session');

    $_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load(1); //here 1 is product Id
    $block =  $this->getLayout()->createBlock('checkout/cart_crosssell')->setProduct($_product)->setTemplate('checkout/cart/crosssell.phtml');
    $this->getLayout()->getBlock('content')->append($block);

    $this->renderLayout();
}
```

and for your 4 product issue please check in your `app/design/frontend/YourPackge/YourTheme/checkout/cart/crosssell.phtml` file any condition who breaks for loop after four product then change it.

to increase limit for cross-sell product follow this quick step

1) copy `app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/Block/Cart/Crosssell.php` file to `app/code/local/Mage/Checkout/Block/Cart/Crosssell.php`

2) find this line and increase limit as per your need `protected $_maxItemCount = 4;`

Comment: Hello - I was not able to do this yet. Your solution now seems like the best one! ;-) I had a friend (who works as a system administrator) look at it via Git but even he wasn't able to find any installation instructions. How does one install and configure this? Thank you so much! :-*

Comment: Hi @Allysin Have you got solution for that

Comment: I will try to upload those files now. One question - on the GitHub page - it keeps mentioning up to 1.4.1. I have 1.9.1 - is that OK?

Comment: Thank you thank you - I am uploading the files now. Which specific file/path should I add the code to?

Comment: Murtuza Zabuawala: I uploaded all of the files that were in the ZIP. All of the files were NEW to my system except for composer.json and modman at the root (I overwrote those). Now - when I go through the checkout process - I don't see anything new. What else do I need to do? Thank you.

Comment: Great great great! I cleared all Cache and re-indexed and now I see another page in the checkout process - index.php/suggest/. It is ENABLED in System - Configuration - TEMPLATES-MASTER --> SuggestPage. The only things is - it doesn't show anything on the Suggest page except for the product (in the left pane) and then the price details in the right pane (There is 1 item in your cart.) And then the buttons EDIT YOUR CART and CHECKOUT. How do I actually make the cross-sell products show on here?

Comment: open template path hint on and see  the teplate and apply my code that I have provide

Comment: I am soooo happy to get this to work! Just make the cross-sell products appear and that will be it! By template path you mean the design template (would that be the Porto theme in my case?) Can you give me an example of a path and a file name where I can put your code to display the cross-sell products? Since all the products will have the SAME cross-sell items it can be anything really - the cross-sell products in each product or I could even put these cross-sell products into a category and display that.

Comment: go to `app/code/community/TM/SuggestPage/controllers/IndexController.php` and add this code in indexAction before renderLayout

Comment: now I get an Error in the order process: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<' in /home/mystore/public_html/app/code/community/TM/SuggestPage/controllers/IndexController.php on line 14

Comment: I figured that before you mentioned it and it seems to work except it shows the products all the way at the very top of the screen (that could work though) but it only shows 4 products :-( Any chance to display all of my cross-sell products? (all 25 of them?)

Comment: you have a nice extension and thank you very much for helping me through the process of installing and configuring that. There may be 2 potential problems for people who want to accomplish what I am trying to do: 1.It changes the check-out process (that's not a problem) but in such a way that  the place where customers can enter a Discount code disappears completely  and 2. I really want to have at least 12 cross-sell products on the page but it only shows 4. Also some people may be concerned with the fact that it shows the cross-sell products at the very top of the page instead of on the page

Comment: @Allysin please look at my updated answer

Comment: I've changed the code in: `app/code/community/TM/SuggestPage/controllers/IndexControlle‌​r.php`.  to reflect what you updated but I get the following Error: **Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file, expecting function (T_FUNCTION) in /home/myuser/public_html/app/code/community/TM/SuggestPage/controllers/IndexController.php on line 23**

Comment: @Allysin please check you are missing } or you have extra { in your code , or you have extra new line in end of file

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20783514/parse-error-syntax-error-unexpected-function-t-function-expecting-on-line

Comment: @Allysin can you please post your whole new indexController File

Comment: sorry - I was missing the closing bracket = **`}`** --) there need to be 2 at the end of the file...that didn't seem to fix the issue with the Discount Code box not showing up - was that suppose to?

Comment: `<?php

class TM_SuggestPage_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action
{
    public function indexAction()
{
    $this->loadLayout()
        ->_initLayoutMessages('checkout/session')
        ->_initLayoutMessages('catalog/session');

    $_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load(1); //here 1 is product Id
    $block =  $this->getLayout()->createBlock('checkout/cart_crosssell')->setProduct($_product)->setTemplate('checkout/cart/crosssell.phtml');
    $this->getLayout()->getBlock('content')->append($block);

    $this->renderLayout();
    }
}`

Comment: @Allysin Discount box Not showing on this page

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/48537/discussion-between-murtuza-zabuawala-and-allysin).

Comment: the enter your discount code thingy just disappeared before (the customers were the ones complaining they can not find it and when I looked for it - I couldn't find it either. When I disabled the extension - it appeared again

Comment: @Allysin on next page you can see the discount box

Comment: @Allysin you can see your discount box on `Base_url/checkout` or `Base_url/checkout/cart` page

Comment: I am trying to get into chat Murtuza but I'm traveling in China and it is very difficult here...one moment please...

Comment: @Allysin add this code `<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('coupon') ?>` in this file `app/design/frontend/base/default/template/tm/suggestpage/cart.phtml`

Comment: I am doing that right now....BTW - I am in chat already ;-)

Comment: --） I only have “**Sales**” in _app/code/local/Mage_   and it does not have any of the other folders in it... (Magento 1.9.1)

Comment: @Allysin create folder and paste that file and change value

Comment: this works! Thank you! The only (last) problem now seems to be with the way the products appear on the extra page - 4 products on the first line, but ONLY 1 on the second, then 4 products on the 3rd line and only 1 on the forth...You can see that if you check the very first product on the front page

Comment: @Allysin this is may be css Issue And If this answer work for you then feel free to accept

Comment: I just did - sorry I didn't do that before...still not sure how things work here! :o) It makes sense what you say about the CSS...I'll have to look into that :-) Where are the CSS files that may control these things located? Thanks for all your help - you are a gentleman and scholar!

Comment: @Allysin please give your site url

Comment: Can I send that to you in a message please?

Comment: change css `/skin/frontend/smartwave/porto/css/configed/design_default.css`

Comment: @Allysin you are always welcome :)

Comment: I have one more question for ya! ;-) Since all the cross-sell products will always be the same for all the regular products but may change (again the change would be effective for all the products) according to season - would there be an easy way to pull products from let's say a specific category on the extra check-out step page INSTEAD of the cross-sell products themselves? That way it would still be (the process of) up-selling but it would always display the same products and I wouldn't have to go through and change the cross-sells manually in every product each time..

Comment: @Allysin yes we can show one category instead of cross-sell

Comment: that sounds fantastic! How can I set that up? :o)

Comment: So can I just replace some code with something like: 
`{{block type="catalog/product_list" category_id="157" template="catalog/product/list.phtml"}}` Would that work you think? :o)

Comment: @Allysin  $block =  $this->getLayout()->createBlock('catalog/product_list')->setCategoryId(157)->setTemplate('catalog/product/list.phtml');
    $this->getLayout()->getBlock('content')->append($block);

Comment: Thank you! Where do I put that code into?

Comment: @Allysin index controller.php just replace with crossseell code

Comment: I replaced the following code with the code you wrote up above but got an Error: `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '?' in /home/magentoDirectory/public_html/app/code/community/TM/SuggestPage/controllers/IndexController.php on line 28` I changed this: `$block =  $this->getLayout()->createBlock('checkout/cart_crosssell')->setProduct($_product)->setTemplate('checkout/cart/crosssell.phtml');
    $this->getLayout()->getBlock('content')->append($block);` What did I do wrong? (in app/code/community/TM/SuggestPage/controllers/IndexControlle‌​‌​r.php)

Comment: What did I do wrong with the code? :-(

Comment: I tried and tried again and I figured out this Error message - the problem was that my text editor actually added some question marks within the code. I corrected that and now have the correct code in (as you posted up above) but I get a different Error now:

Comment: The Error is too long to post in the reply here - I will put it up in the original post all the way at the top of this page...

Comment: Any idea how I can do this? I'm still trying to display products from a category instead of the actual cross-sell products...Thank you! :-*

Comment: I am still working on this...It is really really important I manage to load the products from a category because I need to change them every once in a while and it would be impossible to do that manually via the cross-sells for 1300 products. Would you help me please? Shall I make another bounty on this topic? Thank you

Answer (score 4):

We've implemented something on a client website where you click on proceed to checkout you land on a page before it asking you to add free samples, these are pulled in from a category but would be just as easy to pull in some cross-sell/related products.

Essentially code wise what would have to happen is, a module would have to listen for the event `controller_action_predispatch_checkout_onepage_index` and redirect the user to a page built by that module with the products you require, then after that set a session flag to say this user has already seen this up-sell page and allow them through to the checkout.

I'm not sure if there are any modules out there that currently do this.

As a brief example we have this as our xml:

```
<controller_action_predispatch_checkout_onepage_index>
    <observers>
        <namespace_module>
            <class>namespace_module/observer</class>
            <method>redirectToUpsellOnCheckout</method>
        </namespace_module>
    </observers>
</controller_action_predispatch_checkout_onepage_index>
```

**Edit 15/11/16**
Here's what i have so far, still needs some amends:

app/etc/modules/

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Dc_Crosssells>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>community</codePool>
        </Dc_Crosssells>
    </modules>
</config>
```

app/code/community/Dc/Crosssells/etc/config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Dc_Crosssells>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
        </Dc_Crosssells>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <blocks>
            <dc_crosssells>
                <class>Dc_Crosssells_Block</class>
            </dc_crosssells>
        </blocks>
        <events>
            <controller_action_predispatch_checkout_onepage_index>
                <observers>
                    <dc_crosssells>
                        <class>Dc_Crosssells_Model_Observer</class>
                        <method>controllerActionPredispatchCheckoutOnepageIndex</method>
                    </dc_crosssells>
                </observers>
            </controller_action_predispatch_checkout_onepage_index>
        </events>
    </global>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <beforeyoucheckout>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Dc_Crosssells</module>
                    <frontName>before-you-checkout</frontName>
                </args>
            </beforeyoucheckout>
        </routers>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <dc_crosssells>
                    <file>dc/dc_crosssells.xml</file>
                </dc_crosssells>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

app/code/community/Dc/Crosssells/Model/Observer.php

```
<?php
class Dc_Crosssells_Model_Observer
{
    public function controllerActionPredispatchCheckoutOnepageIndex(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
    {
        if(Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getCrossSellFlag()) {
            Mage::app()->getResponse()->setRedirect(Mage::getBaseUrl() . 'before-you-checkout');
            Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->setCrossSellFlag('true'); 
        }
    }

}
```

That above is enough to redirect the user to another page after hitting going to checkout. Would need to set a flag within this observer to the session and then check if that flag exists, if it does, do the redirect.

Then we can create a controller this will be our "before-you-checkout" page, it creates/renders the layout using a block from the template.
app/code/community/Dc/Crosssells/controllers/IndexController.php

```
<?php
class Dc_Crosssells_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action
{

    public function indexAction()
    {
        $this->loadLayout(array('default'));

        $block = $this->getLayout()->getBlock('before.you.buy')->getBlockHtml('before.you.buy');
        $this->getLayout()->getBlock('content')->append($block);
        $this->_initLayoutMessages('core/session');
        $this->renderLayout();
    }

}
```

We have a block class to house the functions needed by the frontend block, I haven't fully tested this, it is supposed to return a product collection filtered by the category you should have created in the backend, in my case it's category 292.
app/code/community/Dc/Crosssells/Block/BeforeYouBuy.php

```
<?php
class Dc_Crosssells_Block_BeforeYouBuy extends Mage_Core_Block_Template
{
    public function getCrossSellProductsFromCategory()
    {
        $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load(292);

        $products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
            ->addCategoryFilter($category)
            ->addAttributeToSelect('*');

        return $products;
    }
}
```

app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/dc/dc_crosssell.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <beforeyoucheckout_index_index>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="dc_crosssells/beforeYouBuy" name="before.you.buy" template="dc/crosssell.phtml"/>
        </reference>
    </beforeyoucheckout_index_index>
</layout>
```

app/design/frontend/base/default/template/dc/crosssell.phtml

```
<?php $products = $this->getCrossSellProductsFromCategory();

foreach($products as $item) {
    echo $item->getName(). '<br />';
}
```

I haven't fully tested this code properly yet and still needs some work to actually display the products properly with add to cart buttons etc. I've put it in a github repo here: https://github.com/DanCarlyon/MagentoCrossSellPage

Feel free to download and have a play with it.

Comment: what you have sounds exactly like what I need! I don't mind putting all the cross-sell products into a category and having that displayed. Is there any way you could give me more details about how I may be able to implement this? I did manage to actually get an extra step in the check-out process (I installed the "SuggestPage" extension from Murtuza Zabuawala /right above your post here/) but it only displays 4 cross-sell items from the cross-sells that are actually associated with that product in the Admin. Any help would be really appreciated! ;-)

Comment: I will try and update my answer today with a more full solution, i don't really know anything about the suggestpage extension and don't currently have a test environment to test it on. :)

Comment: I'm really interested in this - I think adding the cross-sell products from a category would really do what I am trying to accomplish

Comment: Hi @Allysin really sorry for the delay, i've updated my answer with some of the code i have been able to write, although it's still not quite complete. But there is a github repo where you can download what i have written and have a play with it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this module:

File : app\etc\modules\Rkt_CrossSell.xml

true
            community
            
                
            
        
    

File : app\code\community\Rkt\CrossSell\etc\config.xml

1.0.0
        
    
    
        
            
                Rkt_CrossSell_Helper
            
        
        
            
                Rkt_CrossSell_Block
            
        
    
    
        
            
                
                    rkt_crossell.xml
                
            
        
    

File : app\code\community\Rkt\CrossSell\Block\Catalog\Product\View\Crosssell.php

```
/**
 * Get crosssell items
 *
 * @return array
 */
public function getItems()
{
    $items = $this->getData('items');
    if (is_null($items)) {
        $items = $this->getProduct()->getCrossSellProducts();
        $this->setData('items', $items);
    }
    return $items;
}
```

}
File : app\code\community\Rkt\CrossSell\Helper\Data.php

}
File : app\design\frontend\base\default\layout\rkt_crossell.xml

Now in your view.phtml add this code in the appropriate position

getChildHtml('crosssell') ?> 
Now clear your cache. Double check evey file name and file paths are correct. Then you are good to go

You can add a block on product page or else call the phtml file inside a cms page.

Comment: Thank you for helping. Let me ask you this - Do I understand it correctly that I would insert the code in the grey box into the 5 files you mention and then add the getChildHtml into view.phtml? Would that create an extra page in the check-out process and display the cross-sell products on it? I'm open to any solution that would display at least 12 cross-sell products in such a way that customers just wouldn't be able to miss them...Thank you

Comment: If you want to display all the cross sell product at the time add to cart you can show in popup using the events and observers in Magento. Like you can use  "checkout_cart_product_add_after" and there you have to show all the cross sell product in a popup or as your suggested design.

Comment: You can also perform a ajax add to cart to the cross sell products

Comment: thank you very much for your suggestions. A pop-up sounds wonderful but the problem here is going to be that I am not versed enough in these things to implement it. I can use FTP to upload files and make changes to existing files but without step-by-step instructions - I will not be able to figure out how to set that up... :-(

Comment: For doing so fisrt you have to make a ajax add to cart in your magento. Then using observer you can show the related cross sell or up sell products in a window and there also you have to make an ajax add to cart for the cross sell products. To make this happen you will needing a lot of efforts :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try Below code For category rendering

```
   $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load(157);  
   $block = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('catalog/product_list')->set‌​Data('category_id',$category)->set‌​Template('catalog/pr‌​oduct/list.phtml'); 
   $this->getLayout()->getBlock('content')->append($block);
```

Comment: I did and got an Error also (I posted that Error on top in my original post).

Comment: @Allysin we need to look I cannot say why this error is coming

Comment: @Allysin check updated answer