# How to pull products from a category on an extra check-out step I already have?

Tags: magento-1.9, checkout

I installed a plugin to add an extra check-out step to present more cross-sell products from here:

[How to add a custom page with cross-sell products](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/122348/how-to-add-a-custom-page-with-cross-sell-products?noredirect=1#comment202383_122348)

And it works great - the page comes up and loads the cross-sells but now I need to pull the products from a category instead of the actual cross-sell products because I intend to change the cross-sells every once in a while and it would be nearly impossible to change cross-sells in 1300 products manually...

Any idea how I can do that?

Magento 1.9.1.0

Here is the actual code I used to add the extra check-out step:

https://github.com/tmhub/suggestpage

---

*Edited on January 19th, 2017:*

**Let me just clarify from the very beginning...**

There are a few things I did:

1. I installed the SuggestPage plugin from here: https://github.com/tmhub/suggestpage

that gave me the extra page in the check-out.

Then 2. I modified the IndexController.php file in:

/home/myAccount/public_html/app/code/community/TM/SuggestPage/controllers/backupINDEXCONTROLLER/IndexController.php

In order to:

1. Display cross-sell products on the extra check-out page

and

2. Give the option for customers to enter a coupon.

The original IndexController.php looked liked this:

```
<?php
class TM_SuggestPage_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        $this->loadLayout()
            ->_initLayoutMessages('checkout/session')
            ->_initLayoutMessages('catalog/session');
        $this->renderLayout();
    }
}
```

My modified IndexController.php looks like this:

```
<?php

class TM_SuggestPage_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action
{
    public function indexAction()

{

    $this->loadLayout()
        ->_initLayoutMessages('checkout/session')
        ->_initLayoutMessages('catalog/session');

$block2 =  $this->getLayout()->createBlock('checkout/cart_coupon')->setTemplate('checkout/cart/coupon.phtml');
$this->getLayout()->getBlock('content')->append($block2);

    $_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load(1); //here 1 is product Id
    $block = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('checkout/cart_crosssell')->setProduct($_product)->setTemplate('checkout/cart/crosssell.phtml'); $this->getLayout()->getBlock('content')->append($block);

    $this->renderLayout();
    }
}
```

This works and it works great displaying the cross-sell products!

Now what I am trying to do is display the products from a category (category ID=190) instead of actually displaying the cross-sell products. 
There are 2 gentlemen who have been trying to help me with this and I appreciate that very much - Murtuza Zabuawala and Piyush. They both have different approaches on how to do this:

***Murtuza Zabuawala*** (in his answer below) says to **add the following code** to the **IndexController.php** file in:

/home/myAccount/public_html/app/code/community/TM/SuggestPage/controllers/backupINDEXCONTROLLER/IndexController.php

```
$this->loadLayout()
    ->_initLayoutMessages('checkout/session')
    ->_initLayoutMessages('catalog/session');

 $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load(11); //here 11 is category id
 $block    = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('catalog/product_list')->setCategory($category)->setTemplate('catalog/product/list.phtml');
 $this->getLayout()->getBlock('content')->append($block);
 $this->renderLayout();
```

But when I do that - my IndexController.php file looks like this (**it's possible I am doing it wrong**):

```
<?php

class TM_SuggestPage_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action
{
    public function indexAction()

{

    $this->loadLayout()
        ->_initLayoutMessages('checkout/session')
        ->_initLayoutMessages('catalog/session');

 $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load(190); //here 11 is category id
 $block    = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('catalog/product_list')->setCategory($category)->setTemplate('catalog/product/list.phtml');
 $this->getLayout()->getBlock('content')->append($block);

    $this->renderLayout();
    }
}
```

And it gives the following Error:

```
There has been an error processing your request

SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')' at line 1, query was: SELECT `mg_catalog_category_entity`.* FROM `mg_catalog_category_entity` WHERE (entity_id =)

Trace:
#0 /home/myACCOUNT/public_html/lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
#1 /home/myACCOUNT/public_html/app/code/core/Zend/Db/Statement.php(291): Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_execute(Array)
#2 /home/myACCOUNT/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(480): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
.......

Error log record number: 366748739907
```

If I try to make my IndexController.php like this:

```
<?php



class TM_SuggestPage_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action
{
    public function indexAction()

{

    $this->loadLayout()
        ->_initLayoutMessages('checkout/session')
        ->_initLayoutMessages('catalog/session');


$block2 =  $this->getLayout()->createBlock('checkout/cart_coupon')->setTemplate('checkout/cart/coupon.phtml');
$this->getLayout()->getBlock('content')->append($block2);

    $_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load(1); //here 1 is product Id
    $block = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('checkout/cart_crosssell')->setProduct($_product)->setTemplate('checkout/cart/crosssell.phtml'); $this->getLayout()->getBlock('content')->append($block);


    $this->renderLayout();

     $this->loadLayout()
    ->_initLayoutMessages('checkout/session')
    ->_initLayoutMessages('catalog/session');


 $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load(190); //here 11 is category id
 $block    = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('catalog/product_list')->setCategory($category)->setTemplate('catalog/product/list.phtml');
 $this->getLayout()->getBlock('content')->append($block);


 $this->renderLayout();


    }
}
```

It gives this Error:

```
There has been an error processing your request

SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')' at line 1, query was: SELECT `mg_catalog_category_entity`.* FROM `mg_catalog_category_entity` WHERE (entity_id =)

Trace:
#0 /home/myACCOUNT/public_html/lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
#1 /home/myACCOUNT/public_html/app/code/core/Zend/Db/Statement.php(291): Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_execute(Array)
#2 /home/myACCOUNT/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(480): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
#3 /home/myACCOUNT/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('SELECT `mg_cata...', Array)
....

Error log record number: 988885499570
```

*The truth is - I don't know how to modify the IndexController.php file and it's entirely possible I am doing it wrong and therefore getting these Errors.*

If I try to do what **Piyush** is suggesting (in his answer also below) which is to replace the following code in app/code/community/TM/SuggestPage/Block/Cart.php

```
getLastAddedQuoteItems() function in app/code/community/TM/SuggestPage/Block/Cart.php
```

with this code:

```
public function getLastAddedQuoteItems()
{
    $items = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load('your_category_id')
             ->getProductCollection()
             ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
             ->addAttributeToFilter('status', 1)
             ->addAttributeToFilter('visibility', 4)
             ;
    $this->_lastAddedQuoteItems = $items;

    return $this->_lastAddedQuoteItems;
}
```

then my Cart.php file looks like this (again - **I'm not sure if I'm doing this right**):

```
<?php
class TM_SuggestPage_Block_Cart extends Mage_Checkout_Block_Cart_Sidebar
{
    protected $_lastAddedQuoteItems = null;
    protected function _prepareLayout()
    {
        if (!Mage::registry('product')) {
            $productId = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getSuggestpageProductId();
            if (!$productId) {
                return false;
            }
            $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
                ->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())
                ->load($productId);
            if (!$product->getId()) {
                return false;
            }
            Mage::register('product', $product);
        }
    }
   public function getLastAddedQuoteItems()
{
    $items = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load('190')
             ->getProductCollection()
             ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
             ->addAttributeToFilter('status', 1)
             ->addAttributeToFilter('visibility', 4)
             ;
    $this->_lastAddedQuoteItems = $items;

    return $this->_lastAddedQuoteItems;
}
}
```

and I get the following Error message:

---        Hand Made light was added to your shopping cart.

Fatal error: Call to a member function isVisibleInSiteVisibility() on a non-object in /home/myACCOUNT/public_html/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/cart/sidebar/default.phtml on line 29

*It is also possible that I am modifying this file wrong...*

If I make my Cart.php file look like this:

```
<?php
class TM_SuggestPage_Block_Cart extends Mage_Checkout_Block_Cart_Sidebar
{
    protected $_lastAddedQuoteItems = null;
    protected function _prepareLayout()
    {
        if (!Mage::registry('product')) {
            $productId = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getSuggestpageProductId();
            if (!$productId) {
                return false;
            }
            $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
                ->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())
                ->load($productId);
            if (!$product->getId()) {
                return false;
            }
            Mage::register('product', $product);
        }
    }
    public function getLastAddedQuoteItems()
    {
        if (null === $this->_lastAddedQuoteItems) {
           $items = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load('190')
             ->getProductCollection()
             ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
             ->addAttributeToFilter('status', 1)
             ->addAttributeToFilter('visibility', 4)
             ;
    $this->_lastAddedQuoteItems = $items;

    return $this->_lastAddedQuoteItems;
}
}
```

It gives the following Error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file, expecting function (T_FUNCTION) in /home/myACCOUNT/public_html/app/code/community/TM/SuggestPage/Block/Cart.php on line 34
```

---

*Edited later on January 19th, 2017:*

**Murtuza Zabuawala** (thank you for trying) suggested to try a different code and so I made my IndexController.php in `/home/myACCOUNT/public_html/app/code/community/TM/SuggestPage/controllers/`

look like this:

```
<?php

class TM_SuggestPage_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action
{
    public function indexAction()

    {

        $this->loadLayout()
            ->_initLayoutMessages('checkout/session')
            ->_initLayoutMessages('catalog/session');


     $block = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('catalog/product_list')->setCategoryId(190)->setTemplate('catalog/product/list.phtml'); 
     $this->getLayout()->getBlock('content')->append($block);


        $this->renderLayout();
        }
    }
```

but that gives the following Error:

```
There has been an error processing your request
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')' at line 1, query was: SELECT `mg_catalog_category_entity`.* FROM `mg_catalog_category_entity` WHERE (entity_id =)

Trace:
#0 /home/myACCOUNT/public_html/lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
#1 /home/myACCOUNT/public_html/app/code/core/Zend/Db/Statement.php(291): Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_execute(Array)
#2 /home/myACCOUNT/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(480): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
#3 /home/myACCOUNT/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('SELECT `mg_cata...', Array)
```

...

```
Error log record number: 559785389974
```

Where these are the contents of the 559785389974 log record:

```
**a:5:{i:0;s:307:"SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')' at line 1, query was: SELECT `mg_catalog_category_entity`.* FROM `mg_catalog_category_entity` WHERE (entity_id =)";i:1;s:3928:"#0 /home/myACCOUNT/public_html/lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
#1 /home/myACCOUNT/public_html/app/code/core/Zend/Db/Statement.php(291): Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_execute(Array)
```

### ...

------**Edited on January 18th:**

***I am really open to ANY solution that allows me to up-sell (I'm using this as a business term not Magento jargon here = Would you like some fries with that? kind of a thing...) on a separate page of the checkout (preferably after the customer adds the product and before they login to check out....***

---

**Edited on January 16th in response to an answer given by Piyush bellow:**

***Here is the ORIGINAL Cart.php file*:**

```
    <?php
class TM_SuggestPage_Block_Cart extends Mage_Checkout_Block_Cart_Sidebar
{
    protected $_lastAddedQuoteItems = null;
    protected function _prepareLayout()
    {
        if (!Mage::registry('product')) {
            $productId = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getSuggestpageProductId();
            if (!$productId) {
                return false;
            }
            $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
                ->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())
                ->load($productId);
            if (!$product->getId()) {
                return false;
            }
            Mage::register('product', $product);
        }
    }
    public function getLastAddedQuoteItems()
    {
        if (null === $this->_lastAddedQuoteItems) {
            $itemIds = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getSuggestpageQuoteItemIds();
            if (!$itemIds) {
                return false;
            }
            $items = array();
            $cartItems = $this->getItems();
            foreach ($cartItems as $cartItem) {
                if (in_array($cartItem->getId(), $itemIds)) {
                    $items[] = $cartItem;
                }
            }
            if (!$items) {
                return false;
            }
            $this->_lastAddedQuoteItems = $items;
        }
        return $this->_lastAddedQuoteItems;
    }
}
```

**I changed it to this (as indicated in Piyush's answer):**

```
<?php
class TM_SuggestPage_Block_Cart extends Mage_Checkout_Block_Cart_Sidebar
{
    protected $_lastAddedQuoteItems = null;
    protected function _prepareLayout()
    {
        if (!Mage::registry('product')) {
            $productId = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getSuggestpageProductId();
            if (!$productId) {
                return false;
            }
            $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
                ->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())
                ->load($productId);
            if (!$product->getId()) {
                return false;
            }
            Mage::register('product', $product);
        }
    }
    public function getLastAddedQuoteItems()
{
    $items = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load('190')
             ->getProductCollection()
             ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
             ->addAttributeToFilter('status', 1)
             ->addAttributeToFilter('visibility', 4)
             ;
    $this->_lastAddedQuoteItems = $items;

    return $this->_lastAddedQuoteItems;
}
}
```

**But I get the following Error on the website:**

Product blah blah was added to your shopping cart.

**

> Fatal error: Call to a member function isVisibleInSiteVisibility() on
>   a non-object in
>   /home/myAccount/public_html/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/cart/sidebar/default.phtml
>   on line 29

**

**What am I doing wrong? Please help!**

This is line 29 that the Error message is talking about:

**`$this->_lastAddedQuoteItems = $items;`**

I tried to mess with the closing tags -

```
**}**
```

### add or remove some but it does not seem to help!

My default.‌​phtml in `/home/myAccount/public_html/app/design/frontend/base/default‌​/template/checkout/c‌​art/sidebar/`

looks like this (the entire file):

```
     <?php
        /**
         * Magento
         *
         * NOTICE OF LICENSE
         *
         * This source file is subject to the Academic Free License (AFL 3.0)
         * that is bundled with this package in the file LICENSE_AFL.txt.
         * It is also available through the world-wide-web at this URL:
         * http://opensource.org/licenses/afl-3.0.php
         * If you did not receive a copy of the license and are unable to
         * obtain it through the world-wide-web, please send an email
         * to license@magento.com so we can send you a copy immediately.
         *
         * DISCLAIMER
         *
         * Do not edit or add to this file if you wish to upgrade Magento to newer
         * versions in the future. If you wish to customize Magento for your
         * needs please refer to http://www.magento.com for more information.
         *
         * @category    design
         * @package     base_default
         * @copyright   Copyright (c) 2006-2014 X.commerce, Inc. (http://www.magento.com)
         * @license     http://opensource.org/licenses/afl-3.0.php  Academic Free License (AFL 3.0)
         */
        ?>
        <?php
            $_item = $this->getItem();
            $isVisibleProduct = $_item->getProduct()->isVisibleInSiteVisibility();
            $canApplyMsrp = Mage::helper('catalog')->canApplyMsrp($_item->getProduct(), Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Attribute_Source_Msrp_Type::TYPE_BEFORE_ORDER_CONFIRM);
        ?>
        <li class="item">
            <?php if ($this->hasProductUrl()): ?>
                <a href="<?php echo $this->getProductUrl()?>" title="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getProductName()) ?>" class="product-image"><img src="<?php echo $this->getProductThumbnail()->resize(50, 50)->setWatermarkSize('30x10'); ?>" width="50" height="50" alt="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getProductName()) ?>" /></a>
            <?php else: ?>
                <span class="product-image"><img src="<?php echo $this->getProductThumbnail()->resize(50, 50)->setWatermarkSize('30x10'); ?>" width="50" height="50" alt="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getProductName()) ?>" /></span>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <div class="product-details">
                <a href="<?php echo $this->getDeleteUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->__('Remove This Item') ?>" onclick="return confirm('<?php echo $this->__('Are you sure you would like to remove this item from the shopping cart?') ?>');" class="btn-remove"><?php echo $this->__('Remove This Item') ?></a>
                <?php if ($isVisibleProduct): ?>
                <a href="<?php echo $this->getConfigureUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->__('Edit item') ?>" class="btn-edit"><?php echo $this->__('Edit item')?></a>
                <?php endif ?>
                <p class="product-name"><?php if ($this->hasProductUrl()): ?><a href="<?php echo $this->getProductUrl() ?>"><?php endif; ?><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getProductName()) ?><?php if ($this->hasProductUrl()): ?></a><?php endif; ?></p>
                <strong><?php echo $this->getQty() ?></strong> x

    <?php if ($canApplyMsrp): ?>

            <span class="map-cart-sidebar-item"><?php echo $this->__('See price before order confirmation.'); ?></span>

        <?php else: ?>

        <?php if ($this->helper('tax')->displayCartPriceExclTax() || $this->helper('tax')->displayCartBothPrices()): ?>
            <?php if ($this->helper('tax')->displayCartBothPrices()): ?>
                <?php echo $this->__('Excl. Tax'); ?>:
            <?php endif; ?>
            <?php if (Mage::helper('weee')->typeOfDisplay($_item, array(0, 1, 4), 'sales')): ?>
                <?php echo $this->helper('checkout')->formatPrice($_item->getCalculationPrice()+$_item->getWeeeTaxAppliedAmount()+$_item->getWeeeTaxDisposition()); ?>
            <?php else: ?>
                <?php echo $this->helper('checkout')->formatPrice($_item->getCalculationPrice()) ?>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <?php if (Mage::helper('weee')->getApplied($_item)): ?>
                <br />
                <?php if (Mage::helper('weee')->typeOfDisplay($_item, 1, 'sales')): ?>
                    <small>
                    <?php foreach (Mage::helper('weee')->getApplied($_item) as $tax): ?>
                        <span class="nobr"><?php echo $tax['title']; ?>: <?php echo Mage::helper('checkout')->formatPrice($tax['amount'],true,true); ?></span><br />
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                    </small>
                <?php elseif (Mage::helper('weee')->typeOfDisplay($_item, 2, 'sales')): ?>
                    <?php foreach (Mage::helper('weee')->getApplied($_item) as $tax): ?>
                        <span class="nobr"><small><?php echo $tax['title']; ?>: <?php echo Mage::helper('checkout')->formatPrice($tax['amount_incl_tax'],true,true); ?></small></span><br />
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                <?php elseif (Mage::helper('weee')->typeOfDisplay($_item, 4, 'sales')): ?>
                    <small>
                    <?php foreach (Mage::helper('weee')->getApplied($_item) as $tax): ?>
                        <span class="nobr"><?php echo $tax['title']; ?>: <?php echo Mage::helper('checkout')->formatPrice($tax['amount_incl_tax'],true,true); ?></span><br />
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                    </small>
                <?php endif; ?>
                <?php if (Mage::helper('weee')->typeOfDisplay($_item, 2, 'sales')): ?>
                    <span class="nobr"><?php echo Mage::helper('weee')->__('Total'); ?>:<br /> <?php echo $this->helper('checkout')->formatPrice($_item->getCalculationPrice()+$_item->getWeeeTaxAppliedAmount()+$_item->getWeeeTaxDisposition()); ?></span>
                <?php endif; ?>
            <?php endif; ?>
        <?php endif; ?>

 <?php if ($this->helper('tax')->displayCartPriceInclTax() || $this->helper('tax')->displayCartBothPrices()): ?>
        <?php $_incl = $this->helper('checkout')->getPriceInclTax($_item); ?>
        <?php if ($this->helper('tax')->displayCartBothPrices()): ?>
            <br /><?php echo $this->__('Incl. Tax'); ?>:
        <?php endif; ?>
        <?php if (Mage::helper('weee')->typeOfDisplay($_item, array(0, 1, 4), 'sales')): ?>
            <?php echo $this->helper('checkout')->formatPrice($_incl + Mage::helper('weee')->getWeeeTaxInclTax($_item)); ?>
        <?php else: ?>
            <?php echo $this->helper('checkout')->formatPrice($_incl-$_item->getWeeeTaxDisposition()) ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <?php if (Mage::helper('weee')->getApplied($_item)): ?>
            <br />
            <?php if (Mage::helper('weee')->typeOfDisplay($_item, 1, 'sales')): ?>
                <small>
                <?php foreach (Mage::helper('weee')->getApplied($_item) as $tax): ?>
                    <span class="nobr"><?php echo $tax['title']; ?>: <?php echo Mage::helper('checkout')->formatPrice($tax['amount'],true,true); ?></span><br />
                <?php endforeach; ?>
                </small>
            <?php elseif (Mage::helper('weee')->typeOfDisplay($_item, 2, 'sales')): ?>
                <?php foreach (Mage::helper('weee')->getApplied($_item) as $tax): ?>
                    <span class="nobr"><small><?php echo $tax['title']; ?>: <?php echo Mage::helper('checkout')->formatPrice($tax['amount_incl_tax'],true,true); ?></small></span><br />
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            <?php elseif (Mage::helper('weee')->typeOfDisplay($_item, 4, 'sales')): ?>
                <small>
                <?php foreach (Mage::helper('weee')->getApplied($_item) as $tax): ?>
                    <span class="nobr"><?php echo $tax['title']; ?>: <?php echo Mage::helper('checkout')->formatPrice($tax['amount_incl_tax'],true,true); ?></span><br />
                <?php endforeach; ?>
                </small>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <?php if (Mage::helper('weee')->typeOfDisplay($_item, 2, 'sales')): ?>
                <span class="nobr"><?php echo Mage::helper('weee')->__('Total incl. tax'); ?>:<br /> <?php echo $this->helper('checkout')->formatPrice($_incl + Mage::helper('weee')->getWeeeTaxInclTax($_item)); ?></span>
            <?php endif; ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>

    <?php endif; //Can apply MSRP ?>

        <?php if ($_options = $this->getOptionList()):?>
        <div class="truncated">
          <div class="truncated_full_value">
            <dl class="item-options">
                <?php foreach ($_options as $_option) : ?>
                <dt><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_option['label']) ?></dt>
                <dd>
                    <?php if (is_array($_option['value'])): ?>
                    <?php echo nl2br(implode("\n", $_option['value'])) ?>
                    <?php else: ?>
                    <?php echo $_option['value'] ?>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                </dd>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            </dl>
          </div>
        <a href="#" onclick="return false;" class="details"><?php echo $this->__('Details') ?></a>
        </div>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </div>
```

**Edited on January 20th, 2017:
My IndexController.php looks like this:**

```
<?php

class TM_SuggestPage_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action
{
    public function indexAction()


{

   $this->loadLayout()
    ->_initLayoutMessages('checkout/session')
    ->_initLayoutMessages('catalog/session');


$block2 = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('checkout/cart_coupon')->setTemplate('checkout/cart/coupon.phtml');
$this->getLayout()->getBlock('content')->append($block2);

$_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load(100); 
$block = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('checkout/cart_crosssell')->setProduct($_product)->setTemplate('checkout/cart/crosssell.phtml'); $this->getLayout()->getBlock('content')->append($block);


$this->renderLayout();
    }
}
```

Comment: just check your code you will get the error, you have not closed braces { properly

Comment: @Piyush I tried to mess with the closing tags - 

    **}**

add or remove some but it does not seem to help! Any other ideas? The Error message is talking about line number 29 and that has this: $this->_lastAddedQuoteItems = $items; Please help me with this. I am going to start another bounty on this as soon as the system lets me (I have enough reputation but it's not letting me to start a bounty for some reason)

Comment: Pretty sure you have the wrong line, your error message says `Fatal error: Call to a member function isVisibleInSiteVisibility() on a non-object in /home/myAccount/public_html/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/cart/sidebar/default.phtml on line 29` and you're showing cart code, please provide template code.

Comment: @Summer Developer I have put all the info in much detail into the original post just now  - can you please look at it? I think I may just be modifying the file wrong...Thank you!

Comment: @Summer Developer I'm sorry - where do I get the template code?

Comment: In the directory specified in the error message

Comment: @Summer Developer I think line 29 there should be this:  `$isVisibleProduct = $_item->getProduct()->isVisibleInSiteVisibility();`  I will try to post that file up in my post soon (it's telling me I ran out of space already....)

Comment: @Summer Developer I managed to post that entire file there - it's on the bottom of my original post. Thank you for trying to help! ;-)

Comment: Do you still need an answer

Answer (score 3):

as far as I know add below code in your indexAction That I have given previously

```
 $this->loadLayout()
    ->_initLayoutMessages('checkout/session')
    ->_initLayoutMessages('catalog/session');

 $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load(11); //here 11 is category id
 $block    = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('catalog/product_list')->setCategory($category)->setTemplate('catalog/product/list.phtml');
 $this->getLayout()->getBlock('content')->append($block);
 $this->renderLayout();
```

I am not sure but you can try below code to

```
 $block    = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('catalog/product_list')->setCategoryId(199)->setTemplate('catalog/product/list.phtml'); //here 199 is category Id
 $this->getLayout()->getBlock('content')->append($block);
 $this->renderLayout();
```

**EDIT**

In your indexController indexAction put below code and remove all other code and here 1 is your product Id so you have to update only 1 product ids cross sell product , that way you can solve your problem and close this question

```
$this->loadLayout()
    ->_initLayoutMessages('checkout/session')
    ->_initLayoutMessages('catalog/session');


$block2 = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('checkout/cart_coupon')->setTemplate('checkout/cart/coupon.phtml');
$this->getLayout()->getBlock('content')->append($block2);

$_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load(100); //here 100 is product Id
$block = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('checkout/cart_crosssell')->setProduct($_product)->setTemplate('checkout/cart/crosssell.phtml'); $this->getLayout()->getBlock('content')->append($block);


$this->renderLayout();
```

**Edit 2**

```
$block    = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('catalog/product_list')->setData('category_id',199)->setTemplate('catalog/product/list.phtml'); //here 199 is category Id
 $this->getLayout()->getBlock('content')->append($block);
 $this->renderLayout();
```

Comment: I am going to start a bounty on this question and I have enough reputation but it's not letting me write now....The code you gave me - which code in the Cart.php does it suppose to replace? I am really desperate now ;-(

Comment: @Allysin this code is for IndexController.php file

Comment: When you say "add" - you mean I really just add it or replace some code with this new one? I tried it both ways but it always gives me Errors...Which part of the file would you say I should replace with your code above? I ended up with this but it didn't work either:

Comment: `<?php



class TM_SuggestPage_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action
{
    public function indexAction()


{



   $this->loadLayout()
    ->_initLayoutMessages('checkout/session')
    ->_initLayoutMessages('catalog/session');

 $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load(190); //here 11 is category id
 $block    = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('catalog/product_list')->setCategory($category)->setTemplate('catalog/product/list.phtml');
 $this->getLayout()->getBlock('content')->append($block);
 $this->renderLayout(); 

 
    }
}`

Comment: Any idea on why it's not letting me to start a bounty on this question? According to this:      http://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties I should have all the badges needed and I have 91 reputation points now...I really really need to make this work ;-(

Comment: I even tried this but it gives the following Error message: `There has been an error processing your request
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')' at line 1, query was: SELECT `mg_catalog_category_entity`.* FROM `mg_catalog_category_entity` WHERE (entity_id =)

Trace:`

Comment: `<?php
class TM_SuggestPage_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
      $this->loadLayout()
    ->_initLayoutMessages('checkout/session')
    ->_initLayoutMessages('catalog/session');

 $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load(190); //here 11 is category id
 $block    = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('catalog/product_list')->setCategory($category)->setTemplate('catalog/product/list.phtml');
 $this->getLayout()->getBlock('content')->append($block);
 $this->renderLayout(); 
    }
}`

Comment: I just tried the following code:

Comment: `<?php

class TM_SuggestPage_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action
{
 public function indexAction()
 {
  $this->loadLayout()
   ->_initLayoutMessages('checkout/session')
   ->_initLayoutMessages('catalog/session');
  
  $block2 = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('checkout/cart_coupon')->setTemplate('checkout/cart/coupon.phtml');
  $this->getLayout()->getBlock('content')->append($block2);`

Comment: `$_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load(1); //here 1 is product Id
  $block = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('checkout/cart_crosssell')->setProduct($_product)->setTemplate('checkout/cart/crosssell.phtml');
  $this->getLayout()->getBlock('content')->append($block);

  $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load(190); //here 11 is category id
  $block = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('catalog/product_list')->setCategory($category)->setTemplate('catalog/product/list.phtml');
  $this->getLayout()->getBlock('content')->append($block);

 $this->renderLayout();
 }
}`

Comment: Deleted all Cache and re-indexed but it gives me the following Error:

Comment: There has been an error processing your request
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')' at line 1, query was: SELECT `mg_catalog_category_entity`.* FROM `mg_catalog_category_entity` WHERE (entity_id =)

Trace:
#0 /home/flower/public_html/lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)

Comment: I finally succeeded in putting the 100 reputation points bounty up!  I can give more points later when I earn them....

Comment: I have put all the info in much detail and clarity into the original post just now  - can you please look at it? I think I may just be modifying the file wrong...Thank you! ;-)

Comment: @Allysin check updated answer

Comment: Thank you my friend - I appreciate you! I will try it as soon as I get on the computer  (in a couple of hours). How would the entire  indexAction file look like? Thank you again!

Comment: I tried it many different ways with the new code you put up but it still give me an Error :-( I'll post the details up in my original question...

Comment: I think I am adding/replacing the code wrong. Would you please please post the whole file the way you think it should be? Thank you so much! :o)

Comment: @Allysin I have a different idea you can fetch relative product from 1 product only and update that 1 produts relative product

Comment: That sounds very smart - how do I do that? Thank you.

Comment: @Allysin check edit section in my post

Comment: I was SO excited! I took product #100, put all the cross-sell products in and then put in the code you said into the IndexController.php file in: `public_html/app/code/community/TM/SuggestPage/controllers/` but it doesn't work! :-( It brings up the SuggestPage with the place for the coupon but it does NOT show any cross-sell products... ;-(

Comment: @Allysin give me indexAction code that you have

Comment: I just posted the contents of my updated IndexController.php file up in my original question - it's all the way on the bottom...

Comment: @Allysin I updated the code now check edit section and put that code in your indexController in indexAction

Comment: @Allysin I can see there are 6 products in extra page

Comment: I re-indexed and I think it may actually be working! :-) :-) :-) One moment please while I double check...

Comment: No it doesn't work. I'm not sure what you mean by the 6 products in the extra page? Some products actually have cross-sells assigned to them already and that's probably what you are seeing...If you try any of the products in the first row - they don't display any cross-sell products on the extra SuggestPage..

Comment: product 100 = "24 Premium Rose Cylinder in all colors, awesome" --> it currently has 10 cross-sell products assigned to it. you can find that product through the Search feature...

Comment: I just did an experiment - I put only 4 cross-sell products into the last (forth) flower on the first row = Valentine Red Roses and Hydrangea. When you go through the order process and get to the Extra SuggestPage - it shows those exact 4 cross-sell products on the extra page which means it's just displaying the cross-sell products for whichever product has been added to the cart but it does not pull and show the cross-sell products from product #100.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52120/discussion-between-allysin-and-murtuza-zabuawala).

Comment: I'm just gonna give the 100 reputation points to you because I think you deserve them - you tried real hard to help me...too bad I didn't manage to make this work! :-(

Comment: I mean I will award the 100 points to Murtuza Zabuawala...

Comment: @Allysin I have another idea If you tell me then we can implement

Comment: You are the best! I can do it now... ;-)

Comment: @Allysin join chat

Comment: I awarded the 100 bounty points to Murtuza Zabuawala because he really tried to help me and even though we did not get it to work I appreciate your efforts my friend! ;-) All the best! :o) PS: I may start another bounty as soon as I get enough points for it - I will find a solution eventually! :-)

Comment: @Allysin see edit2 part

Answer (score 3):

As per github url Module provided by you.

You can simply change the product collection of your `getLastAddedQuoteItems()` function of block.

For category product you can use this code in your Modules Block file `Cart.php`-

```
public function getLastAddedQuoteItems()
{
    $items = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load('your_category_id')
             ->getProductCollection()
             ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
             ->addAttributeToFilter('status', 1)
             ->addAttributeToFilter('visibility', 4)
             ;
    $this->_lastAddedQuoteItems = $items;

    return $this->_lastAddedQuoteItems;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! Let me jusk ask this - which file and path should I put this code into? And which code will it replace? Thank you again! :-*

Comment: replace the `getLastAddedQuoteItems()` function in `app/code/community/TM/SuggestPage/Block/Cart.php` File

Comment: I did and it gave me the following Error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'public' (T_PUBLIC) in /home/myaccount/public_html/app/code/community/TM/SuggestPage/Block/Cart.php on line 27

Comment: you have missed something in `cart.php` , check for `{ }` and `;`

Comment: I think you may be right. I posted my cart.php file up above in the original question. Would you look at it please?

Comment: Would you have any other ideas on what I can try? I am still unable to make this work.... ;-(

Comment: I was finally able to start a 100 point reputation bounty on this...Please help me 

Comment: I have put all the info in much detail and clarity into the original post just now  - can you please look at it? I think I may just be modifying the file wrong...Thank you! ;-)