# Add cross-sell block to product page (complication)

Tags: product-page, cross-sells

I found Rajeev K Tomy's answer to this  stackexchange question ([Add Cross sell block on product page](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/79242/add-cross-sell-block-on-product-page)) very helpful to add a cross-sell block to my product page.

After implementing the solution, however, the cross-sell products on my product page do not load their thumbnail image, title, or price correctly.  Instead, the magento placeholder thumbnail loads, the title is absent, and the price displays $0.00.

Interestingly, clicking on the thumbnail redirects to the proper cross-sell product page and the add-to-cart button also preserves functionality.  Furthermore, if I add the original product to the cart, my shopping cart's cross-sell block displays with the proper images,titles, and prices.

Tracking the problem down to crossell.phtml:

> app/design/frontend/my_package/default/template/checkout/cart/crossell.phtml

Why does some of the php (such as the following from crossell.phtml) not work when it is applied to the product page?

`<img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_item, 'thumbnail')->resize(210); ?>" </img>`

`<h3 class="product-name"><a href="<?php echo $_item->getProductUrl() ?>"><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_item->getName()) ?></a></h3>`

`<?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_item, true) ?>`

Any ideas how to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to gain the functionality that was missing by incorporating part of another stackexchange question ([Cross-sell product is not showing in the product detail page](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/95972/cross-sell-product-is-not-showing-in-the-product-detail-page?rq=1)) to the original solution I used ([Add Cross sell block on product page](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/79242/add-cross-sell-block-on-product-page)).

Specifically, edit this file as follows: `app\code\community\Rkt\CrossSell\Block\Catalog\Product\View\Crosssell.php`

```
/**
 * Get crosssell items
 *
 * @return array
 */
public function getItems()
{
    $items = $this->getData('items');
    if (is_null($items)) {
        $items = $this->getProduct()->getCrossSellProductCollection()
    ->addAttributeToSelect(Mage::getSingleton('catalog/config')->getProductAttributes())
    ->setPositionOrder()
    ->addStoreFilter();
        $this->setData('items', $items);
    }
    return $items;
}
```

Hope this helps anyone who runs into the same problem I had.